# Optimization flag on MQL5 compiler?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

Calling `metaeditor64.exe /help` one can see the basic syntax for calling the compiler from the command line. However, [MetaTrader offers a compiler optimization option](https://www.metatrader5.com/en/metaeditor/help/development/compile), which I'm not sure if I'm using or not. Is there any flag that I can use to setup the optimization option? Even the compilation log does not seem to inform which option was set.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? my EA in the MetaEditor compiles in 10 seconds with optimizations and 1 second without.. It would really help to disable optimizations on the command line during development

Comment: @ycomp Never solved the problem. I suspected that it was running with optimization due to the difference I could see in compile times when enabling/disabling optimization on the GUI. Made my peace believing that optimization was on.

Comment: I ask the author of MQL Tools (vs code extension) he says you can't disable optimization via the command line compiler.. his extension has a way to compile with the metaeditor gui as well so that's one way to do it, not ideal of course